# How to pass variable to a subprocess.run in a Python script?

Tags: python, loops, csv

I have following the link:
to incorporate a command line command into my python script and it is working fine. 
but i want o run the command over all the files present in a folder. How to send the file name to the command line? I think there should be some for loop but I cant hit the chord. Also I wnat to save the result in a .csv file.

```
import os
 import subprocess

 list_files = subprocess.run(["file","my_audio.wav"])
```

How to ?

```
for file_name in folder
      output=subprocess.run(["file","file_name"])`
      save output in .csv
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass your process into a command line interface. You can do the whole process in python. Then run the python code to do everything.

Comment: I reframed the question

Comment: You've already figured out the answer yourself using glob pattern I think.

Comment: @mumtaz, have u tried ```os.listdir``` which return's list containing the names of the files in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer !

```
import os
import subprocess
import glob

with open("bit_rate.csv", "w") as fp:
 for file_name in glob.glob('./*.wav'):
    print(file_name)

    subprocess.run(["file",file_name ], stdout=fp)
```